# Protractor unable to find elements and script timeout

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm running protractor, it runs successfully and load my angular app.
The very first test I wrote is to get the sign-up button. Although I can see the sign-up button in my view and I'm targeting it with proper CSS.

Still, all I get is this error after running the test.

```
App
    ✗ should get the text of sign up button
      - Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
        (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615355 (d5698f682d8b2742017df6c81e0bd8e6a3063189),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.2 x86_64)
```

I've tried to increase the `allScriptsTimeout` in the `protractor.conf.ts` file but to no avail.

**app.e2e-spec.ts** file

```
    it('should get the text of sign up button', () => {
      page.navigateTo();
      expect<any>(page.getButtonText()).toEqual('Sign up');
    });
```

**app.po.ts**

```
  getButtonText() {
    return element(by.css('a[data-e2e="nav-signup"]')).getText();
  }

  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/');
  }
```

What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: This error is typically associated with async timeouts, meaning an async function has not completed in the allocated timeout period. Do you have SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER set in your conf? https://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts

Comment: @DublinDev I think I don't have `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER `. Never heard of it. Can you tell me where can I find or how can I fix the above errors?

Comment: [Here is a answer I gave previously regarding the promise_manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54330750/browser-sleep-and-browser-pause-do-not-get-executed/54331633#54331633). It is recommend not disable it and use async/await statement. I will post some code that may assist you

Answer (score 3):

Updated some syntax and removed async/awaits from page object function.

As I mentioned your failure is likely due to an async issue. Can you try changing your code to disable the promise_manager in the conf and use the async/await syntax and see if that helps you?

a previous answer of mine on the [subject of the async/await & the promise manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54330750/browser-sleep-and-browser-pause-do-not-get-executed/54331633#54331633)

Every action that interacts with the browser will need an await before it and every function that contains an await will need to be labeled *async*

**Conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: ['./app.js'],
    // specs: ['./app.js','./app.1.js'],
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false
}
```

**Page Object**

```
getButtonText() {
  return element(by.css('a[data-e2e="nav-signup"]')).getText();
}

navigateTo() {
  return browser.get('/');
}
```

**Spec File**

```
it('should get the text of sign up button', async () => {
  await page.navigateTo();
  expect(await page.getButtonText()).toEqual('Sign up');
});
```

Comment: I've implemented your solution, but it is throwing error says `An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.` So for that I've added ` "lib": [ "es2015" ]` in both of my `tsconfig.json` i.e. inside `/src` and inside `/e2e` directory. But still showing the same error.

Comment: Oh sorry async/await are an feature of ES8 I believe and will not be available to you using the ES5 version. I do not have experience working with es5, are you restricted to use this version or can you upgrade?

Comment: I'm ok to upgrade... I want these tests to work!!!! It's been 10 days... :/

Comment: I would advise upgrading and trying once more with the code I posted. I'm not familiar protractor testing with using a version so far back.

Comment: what do you want me to upgrade? Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: Honestly I intentionally left that vague because I don't have a good understanding the issue myself. I'm going to continue researching but in the meantime [This may be of use](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17645) to you.

Comment: What nodeJS version are you using?

Comment: Node `v10.15.0`

Comment: Couple of nits. I'll let DublinDev make some fixes. Your page object the `await` is not needed with the returned promise which also means that you should remove the `async`. `expect<any>(` looks odd to me. Usually `expect(` should be good enough in both TypeScript and JavaScript. You will also need node 8 as a minimum.

Comment: Thanks cnishina, I made those changes. One thing i could not explain to @YashwardhanPauranik is why he was getting that ES5 error, especially considering he appears to be using node v10.15.0. Do you know anything about that error?