# Protractor: Dashboard filters not being selected

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

I'm using Protractor to do some automated UI testing for my Qlik dashboards. Currently using [this sample dashboard](https://sense-demo.qlik.com/sso/sense/app/dcb7c95a-9ecd-43e2-8786-cae00108a324/sheet/54b60312-68c5-4d92-a225-79326b68ad5a/state/analysis) to run some tests. I plan to just try different combinations of filters to see if any dashboard graphs fail to render.

For the case of the sample dashboard, I intend to just click on each of the 4 filters at the top of the page and select the first option.

For some reason I just can't get protractor to select the filters for me. I always get a timeout error.

I've tried using browser.driver instead of the default browser. I realized that I have to use browser.driver.get('url') or the page won't load. I have no idea why this is so.

Shown below is my current code:

```
describe('Qlik Dashboard Test', function() {
    it('Primary Filter Testing',function(){
        var url = 'https://sense-demo.qlik.com/sso/sense/app/dcb7c95a-9ecd-43e2-8786-cae00108a324/sheet/54b60312-68c5-4d92-a225-79326b68ad5a/state/analysis';
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        // Reference to all filters
        var filter = element.all(by.className('title ng-binding'));
        // Reference to first option in each filter
        var first_opt = element(by.repeater('textItem in item.textItems'));
        // Reference to backbutton
        var bb = element.all(by.className('lui-clear-all lui-icon lui-icon--remove'));
        // Go to website
        browser.driver.get(url);
        // Wait for all filters to be visible
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(filter , 10000));

        // Click on each filter, and select the first avaiable option
        filter.each(function(main_filter){
            browser.actions().mouseMove(main_filter).click().perform().then(function(){
                browser.driver.wait(EC.visibilityOf(first_opt,15000));
            }).then(function(){
                browser.actions().mouseMove(first_opt).click().perform();
            });

        });

        // Click on back button
        bb.each(function(backbutton){
            browser.actions().mouseMove(backbutton).click().perform();
        }).then(function(){
            browser.sleep(2000);
        });


    })
})
```

This is the error message that I keep receiving:

```
    Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
      (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615355 (d5698f682d8b2742017df6c81e0bd8e6a3063189),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.0 x86_64)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working with this:

```
describe('Qlik Dashboard Test', function () {
    it('Primary Filter Testing', async function () {
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

        var url = 'https://sense-demo.qlik.com/sso/sense/app/dcb7c95a-9ecd-43e2-8786-cae00108a324/sheet/54b60312-68c5-4d92-a225-79326b68ad5a/state/analysis';
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        var rain = element(by.className('rain rain-loader qv-block-ui ng-scope qv-fade-out'));
        // Reference to all filters
        var filters = element.all(by.css('.title-wrapper'));
        // Reference to backbutton
        var bb = element.all(by.className('lui-clear-all lui-icon lui-icon--remove'));

        // Go to website
        await browser.get(url);
        await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(filters,15000));
        await browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(rain,15000));
        // Wait for all filters to be visible
        let numFilter = await filters.count();
        console.log(numFilter);

        for (let i = 0; i < numFilter; i++) {
            await filters.get(i).click();
            // Reference to first option in each filter
             var first_opt = element(by.repeater('textItem in item.textItems'));
             var all_opt = element.all(by.repeater('textItem in item.textItems'));
             await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(first_opt, 15000));
             const text = all_opt.get(1).getText();
             console.log(text);
             await first_opt.click();
             await browser.sleep(1000);
        }
    },120000)
})
```

Credit to DublinDev for suggesting sync/async, really made writing tests alot easier.

Also edited the default expected duration of the test, seems like it was too short.

It seems there is a ui blocking component (see rain variable ), that blocks the UI until everything is loaded, so you just gotta wait for the filters to be visible in the DOM, and for the UI blocker to go away, and it'll work.

Comment: In case you aren't aware @John you can accept answers you submit yourself. It may be helpful for further people if you do accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your issues is because that site you have linked is a non-angular site. By default Protractor will wait for the Angular testability attribute of the page to settle before attempting any actions but obviously on a non-angular site this attribute will not exist.

If you add browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) to the beginning of your IT block Protractor will not check for this testability property and proceed.

You may have heard that Protractor uses webdriverJS to interact with the browser which is a powerful tool. WebdriverJS can interact with any browser page, Angular or Non-angular. Protractor wraps webdriverJS to allow for easier testing of angular pages (mainly by waiting for the angular elements to load using the testability element mentioned above).

The reason browser.driver.get() is working because by calling browser.driver... you are interacting directly with the webdriverJS instead of Protractors functionality. WebdriverJS can interact with non-angular sites directly no-problem but then you won't be able to use some of [Protractors useful APIs](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api).

Additionally you should consider disabling the control flow and switching to the async/await syntax. [More info on async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421734/protractor-unable-to-find-elements-and-script-timeout/54422397#54422397)

```
describe('Qlik Dashboard Test', function() {
    it('Primary Filter Testing',function(){
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
        var url = 'https://sense-demo.qlik.com/sso/sense/app/dcb7c95a-9ecd-43e2-8786-cae00108a324/sheet/54b60312-68c5-4d92-a225-79326b68ad5a/state/analysis';
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        // Reference to all filters
        var filter = element.all(by.className('title ng-binding'));
        // Reference to first option in each filter
        var first_opt = element(by.repeater('textItem in item.textItems'));
        // Reference to backbutton
        var bb = element.all(by.className('lui-clear-all lui-icon lui-icon--remove'));
        // Go to website
        browser.get(url);
        // Wait for all filters to be visible
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(filter , 10000));

        // Click on each filter, and select the first avaiable option
        filter.each(function(main_filter){
            browser.actions().mouseMove(main_filter).click().perform().then(function(){
                browser.driver.wait(EC.visibilityOf(first_opt,15000));
            }).then(function(){
                browser.actions().mouseMove(first_opt).click().perform();
            });

        });

        // Click on back button
        bb.each(function(backbutton){
            browser.actions().mouseMove(backbutton).click().perform();
        }).then(function(){
            browser.sleep(2000);
        });
   })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I would assume that the site I have linked is angular, since it contains angular components?

Comment: Oh apologies, I actually missed that. The symptoms you described are consistent with some of the failures I have seen in the past on non-angular sites so I only quickly looked at the site. I'll revise my answer  with something else you can try.

Comment: This site is proving a little more difficult to interact with than I anticipated as I am unfamiliar with this style. I will get back to you in a little while when I have another chance to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a new answer as I do not want to overwrite the information I have already posted for now. I managed to get some of this functionality working using async/await syntax which I recommend you using. If you are just beginning this project this will be an easy change for you.

I did not manager to get the value selecting within the filter but the filter themselves are being selected ok. [I found this discussion with may apply to your app](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3071#issuecomment-205437548). It involves setting rootElement property in conf.

I needed to place in an additional 15 seconds wait after the page was loaded and I am not 100% sure why that is but it could be related to the discussion I linked above.

I have limited angularJS experience but hope I have provided some useful information for you here.

**In conf add**

```
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
```

**Your spec**

```
describe('Qlik Dashboard Test', function () {
    it('Primary Filter Testing', async function () {
        // await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

        var url = 'https://sense-demo.qlik.com/sso/sense/app/dcb7c95a-9ecd-43e2-8786-cae00108a324/sheet/54b60312-68c5-4d92-a225-79326b68ad5a/state/analysis';
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

        // Reference to all filters
        var filters = element.all(by.css('.title-wrapper'));
        // Reference to backbutton
        var bb = element.all(by.className('lui-clear-all lui-icon lui-icon--remove'));

        // Go to website
        await browser.get(url);
        await browser.driver.sleep(15000);

        // Wait for all filters to be visible
        let numFilter = await filters.count();
        console.log(numFilter);

        for (let i = 0; i < numFilter; i++) {
            await filters.get(i).click();

            // Reference to first option in each filter
            // let first_opt = element(by.repeater('textItem in item.textItems')).row(1);

            // await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(first_opt, 15000));
            // await first_opt.click();
            await browser.driver.sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the async/await style, really helps that I don't have to deal with sync and async with protractor, I just have to use 'await' if I want to wait for a promise.
I'll also try to see if I can get the code to work with this. My main aim is to get all the filter values from each of the filters, and permutate everything to try every possible combination.